# Adding Object Storage to /etc/fstab - Getting Parse Error

Tags: mount, fstab, cloud, oracle, storage

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on a cloud instance. This instance is on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI). I created there an object storage that I add manually using the following command

```
s3fs WTX-Cotton-bucket /home/ubuntu/wtx_cotton_storage -o passwd_file=${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs -o url=https://axrpuscetkut.compat.objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com/ -onomultipart -o use_path_request_style -o endpoint=us-ashburn-1 -o nonempty
```

When I reboot the instance. The storage is not mounted. Therefore, I need to add it to /etc/fstab to mounted every time the PC boots. This is my current code to added it:

```
WTX-Cotton-bucket /home/ubuntu/wtx_cotton_storage fuse.s3fs use_path_request_style,passwd_file=/home/ubuntu/.passwd-s3fs,url=https://axrpuscetkut.compat.objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com,endpoint=us-ashburn-1 kernel_cache,multipart_size=128,parallel_count=50,multireq_max=100,max_background=1000,_netdev
```

These are the [instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/s3compatibleapi.htm#Supported_Amazon_S3_Clients) from a oracle site:

```
<bucket_name> /path/to/<local_directory_name> fuse.s3fs use_path_request_style,passwd_file=/root/.s3fs-password,url=https://<namespace_name>.compat.objectstorage.<region_ID>.oraclecloud.com,endpoint=<region_ID> kernel_cache,multipart_size=128,parallel_count=50,multireq_max=100,max_background=1000,_netdev{code}
```

After adding it to /etc/fstab. I do `sudo mount -a` and I get this error message:

```
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 25 -- ignored
```

cat -v /etc/fstab

```
WTX-Cotton-bucket /home/ubuntu/wtx_cotton_storage fuse.s3fs use_path_request_style,passwd_file=/home/ubuntu/.passwd-s3fs,url=https://axrpuscetkut.compat.objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com,endpoint=us-ashburn-1 kernel_cache,multipart_size=128,parallel_count=50,multireq_max=100,max_background=1000,_netdev
```

Comment: Oracle has told me to remove {code}, but still not working.

Comment: The error message states line 25 is in error but you don't explicitly list line 25.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix the files has other 24 lines that are commented out. This error belongs to the line mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of working with the support team from Oracle, they have provided me the successful code to automatically mount the object storage after reboot:

```
WTX-Cotton-bucket /home/ubuntu/wtx_cotton_storage fuse.s3fs allow_other,use_path_request_style,passwd_file=/home/ubuntu/.passwd-s3fs,url=https://axrpuscetkut.compat.objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com,endpoint=us-ashburn-1,kernel_cache,multipart_size=128,parallel_count=50,multireq_max=100,max_background=1000,_netdev
```